How can non-additive metrics, such as 'unique visitors,' be calculated with low latency for custom date ranges?
I'm building an analytical solution with a worker to calculate 30-day statistics and a UI to display them.
Currently, the UI uses a fixed last 30 days date range, but I want to support custom date ranges with millisecond response times.
Additive metrics like video_views can be pre-calculated daily and summed for any date range.
However, non-additive metrics, such as unique_videos and unique_visitors, require a different approach since they need to account for unique values.
How can I handle non-additive metrics efficiently?
Notes:

20 million daily active users
50 million daily events
Current solution based on AWS (ECS, Redshift, RDS)
Raw data is clickstream


My approach involves creating collections of unique values on a daily basis and accelerating queries using techniques like HyperLogLog. But what if the results shouldn't be approximated?

Within what timeframe must stats like unique_[thing] be updated once an event has occurred?

Do you need accurate numbers for any arbitrary time frame? Or approximation is also acceptable?

@AdrianK, hi!
There isn't a specific timeframe for stats updates after an event occurs, as this isn't a real-time tracking application. We update metrics daily, so the most recent data available should be from the previous day.
The UI response time is 1 second.
I hope I understood your message correctly. If not, feel free to clarify.

@PeterCsala, hi! For some of the non-additive metrics, I can use approximations—for example, for unique_visitors. However, for a few of them, it's not acceptable.

I don't have experience designing systems with that level of activity, so I'll be interested to see what other ideas are put forward.
The overall process has two parts: capture raw event data; pre-calculate periodic stats for the UI / reporting.

Gather data: when a given event occurs (new session, or new video added) capture the essential info and throw it in a queue to be processed.  Could be one queue or one queue per event-type, whatever you think will be best.
Processing: Process items in the queue(s), adding 1 new entry/record per event.
Processing option: employ a cache of some kind - update that at the same time you process the each result, using a caching pattern like write-aside, write-behind. This part might be needed if you have high transaction volumes and need fast performance.
Data structure / solution (for raw event data): use a NoSQL database of some kind, like DynamoDB.  Have a "table" per event of interest.
Data structure / solution (for pre-calculated): anything you like, that is convenient for storing the report data.

To get the value-counts, pre-calculate value-counts periodically (e.g. every 5 mins, hourly or daily - whatever you need) - assuming that is functionally acceptable.
Update

We update metrics daily, so the most recent data available should be from the previous day. The UI response time is 1 second.

So, is your issue that you want 'UI response time is 1 second' and you are trying to calculate unique_visitors on-the-fly in response to a UI request?  If 'this isn't a real-time tracking application' then simply pre-calculate the desired stats.  You should be able to have some sort of routine periodically scan a given set of data, calculate the various stats you need and "publish" those to a separate summary table(s) where they can be easily an quickly read.  When you say 'We update metrics daily' I'm wondering if that's what you are already doing?
Database design - use two sets of tables:

First set is designed to hold the raw event data.
Second set is designed to hold the pre-compiled daily stats.

For the pre-calculation, there's probably a variety of ways of doing that - perhaps a lambda function.
You may also want to perform clean-up operations on the raw data, depending on how long you want to keep it available in the raw event tables.
I've also updated my initial answer to better reflect the additional info from your comments.

Thank you for your thoughts, Adrian!
DynamoDB does indeed look promising in terms of response time, especially with DAX enabled.
Additionally, there is built-in deduplication logic.
However, as far as I know, calculating unique values easily isn't possible.
But I might be wrong. Here's what I know about the available options for counting:
Atomic counters: They might help with the total count of unique values over time, but it seems they don't address the issue of uniqueness within a specific date range.
Scan counting: This might work, but the performance needs to be tested.

We have used the following technique to be able to tell how many unique sessions were in any arbitrary time window. So, each session has a start and an end. Or more precisely a first seen and a last seen attribute. When we saw a new session id then we created a new record with the first seen in a database. In every minute we have updated the active sessions' last seen attribute with current timestamp.
We have used Aurora Postgres database due to its time range overlap support.
Here is a simplified version of the table schema:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_sessions(
    session_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL, -- UUID with hyphens
    duration tsrange,
    -- rest of the dimensions
);

The only thing that is worth calling out is the usage of the tsrange type.
Here is a simplified upsert stored procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE unique_session_upsert(
    sessionId CHAR(36),
    lastSeen TIMESTAMP(0) without time zone
    ... -- dimensions
) LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO unique_sessions(session_id, duration, ...)
        VALUES (sessionId, tsrange(lastSeen - interval '1 minute', lastSeen), date_trunc('day', lastSeen)), ...)
        ON CONFLICT(session_id) DO UPDATE
            SET duration = tsrange(least(lower(unique_sessions.duration), lastSeen), greatest(upper(unique_sessions.duration), lastSeen))
            WHERE excluded.session_id = sessionId;
    END; $BODY$

And of course you have to create a gist index to make the overlap operator efficient:
CREATE INDEX unique_sessions_idx ON unique_sessions USING GIST (duration);

and finally the query:
SELECT count(1) FROM unique_sessions
WHERE duration && tsrange(query_start, query_end, '[]')
-- AND rest of the dimension filters 

You might need to consider to partition your table (based on the day) to make the table and the query scalable.

UPDATE #1
So, if you need to partition your table per day then the table schema would change like this:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_sessions(
    session_id CHAR(36) NOT NULL, -- UUID with hyphens
    -- rest of the dimensions
    duration tsrange,
    day date not null default now(),
    unique (session_id, day)
) partition by range (day);

Then the upsert logic needs only a tiny adjustment: from ON CONFLICT(session_id) to ON CONFLICT(session_id, day).
There are several things worth mentioning:

The continuous update of the sessions can result in a large number of dead tuples. So, you either have to do VACUUM-ing periodically on schedule or you should enabled the auto vacuum feature
Please bear in mind that whenever you use partitions then write distribution is uneven. Usually the current day's partition is under load while others are under.
It might happen that one session has started at the end of Day 1 and lasted on the beginning of Day 2. Because you have partitioned the table that's why the above SELECT COUNT(1) query would count the session twice. You have to use distinct count to solve this problem. Something like this:

WITH sesions AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT session_id
    FROM unique_sessions
    WHERE duration && tsrange(query_start, query_end, '[]')
    GROUP BY session_id
    )
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM sesions;


Wow, this one looks interesting—definitely worth trying.
For my case, using the daterange data type instead of tsrange seems even better.

The logic in pseudocode might look like this: Are there any records saved from yesterday for the entities that are active today? If YES -> update the right boundary of the daterange for those entities. If NO -> create new records for them.
This could be helpful when there are gaps in active traffic for certain entities on specific days.
For example, I have clickstream data for the range DAY 1 to DAY 3.
The entity was active only on DAY 1 and DAY 3.
If I request data for DAY 2 specifically, I shouldn’t receive anything.

These range data types also appear to be supported in both pure PostgreSQL and Aurora PostgreSQL.

@Alex I've updated my post to add more information about day based partitioning.
